# Create a square that rolls across the screen

Tags: python, algorithm, graphics

This is for a computer science assignment using Python, does anybody know where I would begin to create an algorithm to create a square or box that rolls across the screen? And I do indeed mean roll, not slide. It does not necessarily have to be using python, I just need a general idea as to how the coordinates would work and a general algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a unit square starts out with one side resting on the x-axis, and the lower right corner at (xs, 0), then after a quarter turn clockwise it will again have one side resting on the x-axis, and the lower right corner now at (xs+1, 0).  Before it turns, label the lower left corner a; the upper left, b; and the upper right, c.  Corners a and c move along arcs of a unit circle as the square turns.  Corner b moves with radius d = sqrt(2).

This leads to the following method:  Step angle t from 0 to pi/2 (ie 90°), letting
• xa = xs - cos t
• ya = sin t
• xb = xs - d*cos(t+pi/4)
• yb = d*sin(t+pi/4)
• xc = xs + sin t
• yc = cos t

At each time step, erase the old square by drawing background-colored lines, compute new (xa,ya,xb,yb,xc,yc) from equations, draw new square with lines from (xs,0) to (xa,yb) to (xc,yc) to (xd,yd) to (xs,0), and then delay appropriate amount.  Each time t gets up to pi/2, set t back to 0 and add 1 to xs.  Note, instead of erasing the whole square and then drawing the new, one might try erasing one old line and drawing one new line in turn for the four sides.

Comment: As a general rule it is a bad idea to erase old lines by drawing new lines over them, but instead to replace the whole dirty area with a background color or image.  This is true for a number of reasons, including that it generalizes to drawing over an arbitrary background, that it avoids artifacts introduced by antialiasing and compositing, and that redraws of complex scenes can be handled  efficiently by keeping track of "dirty rects".

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by first thinking about the box pivoting on one corner from one side to the next, and then combine those steps in a sequence.  That is, if you have a box like

```
A ---- B
|      |
C ---- D
```

Rolling to the right, then first the whole thing pivots about D until you have

```
       C - A
       |   |
       |   |
       |   |
       |   |
       D - B
```

That step is a straightforward clockwise rotation of all the points around the origin D by an angle theta between 0 and 90 degrees. I'll leave figuring that out to the asker and/or wikipedia ;).

Once you have figured that step out, the next part of the rotation is the same, except now you are rotating around B instead of D.  This brings you to

```
           D ---- C
           |      |
           B ---- A
```

So at a high level, I would compute the locations of the corners at time t by first figuring out the most recent "flat" configuration, then figure out which corner is in the front, then rotating the points about the front corner based on how much time has elapsed since the square was in that flat state.

As a bonus hint, divmod is a nice function in python for breaking the timestamp into a pair of (which step am I on, how far am I into that step).

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively completely break the spirit of the assignment by using pybox2d, pymunk or another physics engine to do all the calculations for you.  Then you could have lots of boxes rolling around and bouncing off each other :D